# Advanced mass replace with sequence in Notepad++

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++

So I've got 116 html files and all have following code:

**file 1.html:**

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =0;</script>
... code code code...
```

**file 2.html:**

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =0;</script>
... code code code...
```

and so on...

**file 116.html:**

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =0;</script>
... code code code...
```

**Looking for a solution to get something like this:**

**Result:**

**file 1.html**:

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =1;</script>
... code code code...
```

**file 2.html:**

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =2;</script>
... code code code...
```

and so on...

**file 116.html:**

```
....bla bla bla....
<script>var ppgnum =116;</script>
... code code code...
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you have 116 files that duplicate the same `<script>` block in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Using vim

---

In vim, add all the files as arguments (e.g. by starting as `gvim file*.html` or doing `:args file*.html`):

```
:argdo let @n=substitute(expand('%'),'\v^.{-}(\d+).*$', '=\1;','g') | s/var ppgnum \zs=0;/\=@n/
```

Now, save them all and done (`:wqa`)

#### 2. On the command line

---

Or use sed:

```
for filename in file*.html
do 
     sed -i "s/var ppgnum =0;/var ppgnum =${filename//[^0-9]/};/" "$filename"
done
```

See the latter **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d677f187d7942436)**

Comment: for some reason I got this on (Win Vista- GNU sed version 4.2.1) - 

`sed -i "s/var ppgnum =0;/var ppgnum =${filename//[^0-9]/};/" "$filename"`

result

`sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to 's`

Comment: @user3739228 your shell doesn't do parameter substitution (the `${filename//[^0-9]/}` part). I use bash (on cygwin too).

Comment: my actual file names are as follows: a (1).html, a (2).html, ..., a (116).html also I can rename my files any suggestions? By the way your answer is **awesome**

Comment: @Xon both approaches already work with those names with _zero_ modification (see for example [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95c53938dca4c793)). I guess my answer really _was_ awesome then :)

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of **sehe** I changed code and with a help of excel I executed following command on cmd

`sed -i "s/var ppgnum =0;/var ppgnum =1;/" "1.html"`

......................................

`sed -i "s/var ppgnum =0;/var ppgnum =116;/" "116.html"`

It took just 5min to get result :-P   Excel is the best ;)